# Find substrings in binary string

Tags: python, string, binary, substring

I am given string of `0`s and `1`s, and have to find distinct number of substrings such that:

1. number of `0`s and `1`s should be same
2. `1`s should come after `0`s.

So, for example given `001101` answer would be `2: 0011, 01`
Any suggestions? I could not come up with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just generating `01`, `0011` and so on, checking whether each of them is in the given string, and then counting the number of such occurrences?

```py
s = '001101'

substrings = [t for x in range(1, len(s) // 2 + 1) if (t := '0' * x + '1' * x) in s]
print(substrings, len(substrings)) # ['01', '0011'] 2
```

This uses list comprehension with "Walrus" operator (introduced in python 3.8).